# I had knee surgery on my left knee

Tags: injury

I had knee surgery on my left knee and I am finding it difficult for me to clip into my pedals on my road bike and then pedal due to no enough float. Are there pedals and cleats with more float so my knee/leg can be slightly roatated outwards?

Comment: What pedal system are you using?

Comment: Because we don't know what your current setup is, I have closed this question as "unclear what you are asking." If you edit that information in, the question will automatically be flagged for re-opening.

Comment: If you just need your knee to be rotated outwards, you can likely just adjust the cleat to a more suitable position.